# How to re-enable graphic driver on a CentosVM?

Tags: virtualbox, drivers, centos

I'm working on a Centos 07 virtual machine with Gnome desktop hosted on VirtualBox.

Today I perform a "yum update", it upgrades 2K package, and when I reboot I see my screen resolution restricted to 1024x768.

lspci give me no kernel driver in use:

```
lspci -k
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
```

With no driver I agree that my Xrandr give me limited options:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    1024x768      61.00* 
    800x600       61.00  
    640x480       60.00
```

I try to remove/install `xorg-x11-drv-vesa.x86_64` but actually I don't really know which driver I should (re)install on a VM...

How can I re-enable my graphics driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its VirtualBox which provide this driver. Just re-install them with Yum (does not work through VirtualBox's image CD) :

```
sudo yum install VirtualBox-guest-additions.x86_64
```

Then restart and all is fine:

```
lspci -k
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: vboxvideo
    Kernel modules: vboxvideo
```